# Need to paste values, not the formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a generated table created with a Macro, the 1st cell is referencing a dynamic cell that changes with each created table.  However, when the table is created I want the value that is carried into the cell to be pasted as a value and stay as is.  I don't want it to change as the reference cell changes with the next created table. Current code is below, I tried it 2 different ways and the first column continues to change as the reference cell changes.  Any help on how to alter this code so that the value copies in and stays would be great!

```
   objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = _
        "=CB5"
```

Comment: Try `objTable1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = objTable1.Parent.Range("CB5").value` (not tested)

Comment: So this worked, only it didnt do the auto-filldown that was occuring before.  Under CB5 is a continuing list that was copying downwards in the column within the list object.   This code is only copying CB5 and leaving everything under it blank.

Comment: In VBA, you usually don't let Excel do anything unless you can't help it i.e. you don't populate a cell and expect Excel to autofill. Please share the complete code to be able to receive a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusted the solution from comment:

```vb
With objTable1.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    .Value = objTable1.Parent.Range("CB5").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value
End With
```